# Unable to build NextJS app locally when using Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm building a web app and am fetching data from the Firestore both on the client and on the server with `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`.

All has been working fine for months as I've only been running `next build` when deploying my app on Vercel.

I'm now trying to build my app locally, but get the following error

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.6.2): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/.../.next/serverless/protos/google/firestore/v1/firestore.proto'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at fetch (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:70692:34)
    at Root.load (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:70726:13)
    at Root.loadSync (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:70767:17)
    at Object.loadSync (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:43330:29)
    at loadProtos (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:16365:41)
    at newConnection (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:16386:18)
    at OnlineComponentProvider.exports.modules.6631.OnlineComponentProvider.createDatastore (/Users/.../.next/serverless/chunks/254.js:21071:26)
```

I'm pretty stumped so any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After removing code line by line, it ended up being an old setting in the `next.config.js` file.

Removing this fixed the issue

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  target: 'serverless'
};
```